# Octave install error on Mac El Capitan

Tags: macos, octave

When I tried to install Octave (brew install octave --with-gui --HEAD) on OS X 10.11.2 I got this error:

```
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/octave/HEAD --enable-dependency-tracking --enable-link-al
==> make all DOC_TARGETS=
Last 15 lines from /Users/macbookpro/Library/Logs/Homebrew/octave/03.make:
GEN scripts/plot/util/gnuplot_binary.m
GEN doc/interpreter/contributors.texi
GEN etc/icons/octave-logo-256.png
./build-aux/missing: line 81: rsvg-convert: command not found
WARNING: 'rsvg-convert' is missing on your system.
You might have modified some files without having the proper
tools for further handling them. Check the 'README' file, it
often tells you about the needed prerequisites for installing
this package. You may also peek at any GNU archive site, in
case some other package contains this missing 'rsvg-convert' program.
make[2]: *** [etc/icons/octave-logo-256.png] Error 127
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Updating ./doc/liboctave/version-liboctave.texi
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: hav you tried brew install librsvg ?

Comment: Thanks a lot Gerard. That solved the problem.

Comment: BTW, i will add it as an answer. Can you accept it, please ?

Answer (score 1):

Just install this lib:

```
brew install librsvg
```